# How to extract each character in a textarea using Javascript (not jQuery) Better explained

Tags: javascript

I have a straight forward classic ASP page that uses a  where the user can enter any standard keyboard key plus the Enter key (and even special ALT nnn values if they so desire)

My clarification is that I need to display an accurate character count back to the user on each ONKEYUP.  So I need to know if the ENTER key has been pressed (/n) which needs to be counted as 2 chars as well as 8 other chars such as Tilde, Caret Left curly bracket, etc. which also count as 2 characters.  Finally I need to validate each ONKEYUP char to ensure that they will be valid SMS chars, if not they need to be replaced in the TextArea with and Underscore (account as 1 char only)

So what I need to do is to be able to validate each character on the ONKEYUP remembering that a char could be inserted anywhere in the TextArea, an existing char could be deleted from the TextArea or parts of or the entire text could be pasted at any time

The current HTML code is as follows:

```
Enter your message - Characters left &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="chl" value="<%=Cclen%>" size=3 diabled readonly>
<br />
<textarea id="SMSmsg" name="SMSmessage" MAXLENGTH="600" rows=5 cols=35 onKeyUp="textCounter 
(this)"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="chl" value="<%=Cclen%>" size=3 diabled readonly>
<br />
<textarea id="SMSmsg" name="SMSmessage" MAXLENGTH="600" rows=5 cols=35 onKeyUp="textCounter
(this)"></textarea>
```

The JavaScript function testcounter is as follows:

```
function textCounter() {
    var extra = 0;
    var nextra = 0;
    var msgLength = 160 - (document.gs.SMSmessage.value).length - (document.gs.SMSbot.value).length;
    var index = document.gs.SMSmessage.value.indexOf('\n');
    while (index != -1) {
        extra += 1;
        index = document.gs.SMSmessage.value.indexOf('\n', index + 1);
    }
    Canam = nameCounter()
    if (document.gs.SMSrequest.value == 'eml') {
        extra = 0
        nextra = 0
        chnl = 999
    } else {
        if (document.gs.chnl.value > 0) {
            nextra = 3
        }
    }
    document.gs.chl.value = msgLength + extra - nextra;
    Camsg = textWarning();
}
function nameCounter() {
    var botLength = (document.gs.SMSbot.value).length;
    document.gs.chnl.value = botLength;
}
function textWarning() {
    var Ccwarn = " ";
    if (document.gs.chl.value < -299) {
        Ccwarn = "** Error ** - Extended text too long"
    } else {
        if (document.gs.chl.value < 0) {
            if (document.gs.chex.value == 'N') {
                Ccwarn = "** Error ** - Standard text too long"
            } else {
                Ccwarn = "** Warning ** - Extended text - Additional charge applied"
            }
        }
    }
    document.gs.chw.value = Ccwarn;
}
```

Any suggestions as to how to recode the JS function much appreciated taking into account my comments on the user actions within the TextArea

Comment: Why do characters like tilde and curly bracket count as 2 characters?

Comment: It is standard practise in the SMS world. All of the SMS gateways I use require the text to be URL encoded and the Newline and the 8 special chars take up 2 chars when sent as an SMS, Thanks

Comment: You never said anything about URL-encoding in the question. Why don't you just use `encodeURIComponent(value).length`?

Comment: Please don't repost. You can edit the original question.

Comment: I should have mentioned I do use the classic asp Server.URLEncode function but that is after I know the true chars in the text box.  Knowing the overall length is fine but if I send (say) a Tilde char in a SMS text message without telling the Gateway that the length is now +1, I will get charged for 2 or more SMS credits if it goes over 160 or 306 chars so knowing the true length of all chars before sending it off as a HTTP call is critical to my business (as I run a wholesale SMS business on behalf of my clients)

Comment: Re reposting, I couldn't see where to edit my question and my clarification was quite different to the original.  Hope I haven't broken any rules